# I modified the auto-increment on an index and when I create a new record I get 2 new records

Tags: record, auto-increment

When I create a new record I get 2, each with a different index value.
I wanted to add auto increment to my index, and I did, but it was already defined as auto-increment, so I did it twice!! How can I put it back to what it was??

Comment: Which database? How exactly did you modify the index? Please see [ask].